# How to get Hours from a date using java

Tags: java, time, date-format, simpledateformat

What is the date format to get only hours in `12-hours` format from this time

```
 Thu Oct 20 13:12:00 GMT+02:00 2011
```

### edit:

using this code

```
Date eventDate = tempAppointments.get(i).mStartDate
System.out.println(eventDate.toString());

// date pattern
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:'00' a");//output : Wed Nov 09 11:00:00 GMT+02:00 2011


// get the start date with new format (pattern) 
String hours = df.format(tempAppointments.get(i).mStartDate.getDay());
System.out.print(hours);//output: 02:00 AM
```

return hours as

```
02:00 AM
```

but for the given time. it must be `02:00 PM` . why ?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to diagnose the problem if you could provide complete, running code that demonstrates the problem - see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are passing `date.getDay()` (which is deprecated, by the way) into the formatter if you want the hour part.

Try this:-

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("Date: " + date);

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:'00' a");
String hour = df.format(date);
System.out.println("Hour: " + hour);
```

The output:

```
Date: Sat Nov 19 17:57:05 CST 2011
Hour: 05:00 PM
```

Comment: the question is why does it even compile? i don't see any DateFormat#format(int) so what gives?

Comment: You are formatting the date object, not int. See the API here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29

Comment: yes, the problem is that Date#getDay() returns int (in the original code that is)

Comment: even df.format(1) compiles. Is there some implicit casting from int to Date?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Date fecha = new Date();
    System.out.println("Fecha  "+fecha);

    DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    String hora = formato.format(fecha);
    System.out.println("Son las "+hora);
```

Comment: You should indicate why this solves the problem in question.